# Detecting source of change on Controlled Editor in monaco-react | Preventing onChange Event on programmatic value change in monaco-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

This question is concerning [monaco-react](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react) library.

I am using the `onChange` event to detect changes in the editor and call my function to process those changes. This is working fine.

Sometimes, I also set the value in the editor by using the `value` prop on the `ControlledEditor`, which in turn is controlled by the `state` in my component. So when the `state` changes, the text in the editor also updates using the `value` prop.
However, during this change, the `onChange` event is also triggered by the `ControlledEditor` thereby again calling my `onChange` handler. I would like to detect and stop this change event from firing when I update the text in the editor programmatically using the value prop.

How can I detect and prevent the `onChange` event from firing when the value is changed programmatically?

I checked with a normal text field and it does not fire a change event when the value is set programmatically. The change event is fired only when the user focuses on types in the text input field.

Attaching codesandbox link to illustrate this further: https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editorreact---controlled-editor-2-cs717?file=/src/index.js

**Note:** The `onChange` is fired on each change in the Editor - whether it is programmatic or direct change. Check the console for logs of events.

In the case of normal text input, the change is fired only when we directly make changes in the input box. It does not fire when we update the value using the button click which updates the state.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with an earlier version of the library and the developer has fixed this issue with v3.6.1
Attaching a link to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react/issues/91